# PhoneGap Screenshot plugin for Android

Tags: android, cordova, screenshot

I have followed the steps of the following link to capture screenshot with phonegap and android, but I am not clear now which function I should call.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/Screenshot/README.md

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Javascript**

```
$('#save').click(function(){
window.plugins.screenshot.saveScreenshot();
});
```

---

**Html**

```
   <button id="Save">Save</button>
```